# Execution Plan missing Actual Partitions Accessed

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

Using Azure Sql Database, SQL Server Management Studio V. 18.0 Preview 6 (though this problem existed when I was using v 17).
When viewing the execution plan against a partitioned table, the only partition related info I get when I view the properties of a partitioned clustered index seek is "Partitioned | True" (nothing in the XML version either).  Nowhere do I see "Actual Partitions Accessed" as is pictured in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348004/execution-plan-on-table-partitioning) (as example).
Why is it missing?

Comment: are you looking at the actual execution plan? Not the estimated or cached one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was exceedingly simple; @MartinSmith comment (why can't I at mention here?) - include actual execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, I’m using SSMS 18 Preview 7 and I get those properties on Azure and SQL 2019 (just as a quick test).

Azure:

[image: Azure]

SQL 2019:

[image: SQL 2019]

Example I used:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf_test(INT) 
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (0)

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ps_test 
AS PARTITION pf_test ALL TO ([PRIMARY])

CREATE TABLE Foo 
( 
    WorkItem INT NOT NULL 
    , Payload CHAR(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT REPLICATE ('X', 300) 
) ON ps_test(WorkItem)

INSERT INTO Foo (WorkItem) VALUES (-1) 
INSERT INTO Foo (WorkItem) VALUES (-1) 
INSERT INTO Foo (WorkItem) VALUES (2) 
INSERT INTO Foo (WorkItem) VALUES (1) 
INSERT INTO Foo (WorkItem) VALUES (1) 
INSERT INTO Foo (WorkItem) VALUES (2)

SELECT * FROM Foo 
WHERE WorkItem > -1
```

Comment: Thanks for the script; I probably should've included that myself :/